# Nginx Unkown File when restarting after changing default

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, ghost

I want to set my blog to point towards yourdomainanme/blog and to host a static page on the default yourdomainname.com. I changed the paths but It does not find the html file for some reason.

**Error**

```
    nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "home" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:14
    nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

**My Default File**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name yourdomain.com; # Replace with your domain

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 10G;

    location / {
        root var/www/;
        home home.html;
    }

    location /blog {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are confusing the non-existent `home` keyword with the `index` keyword, which tells NGINX the 'default' or 'index' file in the root directory.

```
location / {
    root var/www/;
    home home.html;
}
```

should be

```
location / {
    root var/www/;
    index home.html;
}
```